# Firestore Emulator in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

I'm trying to connect using python 3.8 to the firestore emulator 8.12. I'm having difficulty finding a way to connect. I've downloaded my key from Firestore in the cloud. But I'm trying to connect locally. What does local.json file look like to connect to the emulator locally?

```
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "local.json"

firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db=firestore.client()

data = {
    u'name': u'Los Angeles',
    u'state': u'CA',
    u'country': u'USA'
}

# Add a new doc in collection 'cities' with ID 'LA'
db.collection(u'cities').document(u'LA').set(data)
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/555) on the repo, it seems the Python Admin SDK also needs to the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable to be set.

```
os.environ["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1:8080"
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "emulator_config.json"
docs = db.collection(u'insights/venues/queue').stream()
```

Comment: How to get `emulator_config.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous credentials. From google-auth docs:

> These are useful in the case of services that support anonymous access
> or local service emulators that do not use credentials.

If you don't provide credentials, then it will use  default credentials like you do and describet [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default)

```
from google.auth import credentials
from google.cloud import firestore
        
client = firestore.Client(credentials=credentials.AnonymousCredentials())
```

FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST needs to be set